# How to use session variables to output logged in username and properties

Tags: php, session, dreamweaver

I'm building an application and have just added a Login page which works well, communicating with a "username" and "password" field in the database. After logging in, it takes you a page users are authorized to see.

Is there a way I can display "Welcome, xxx" to the particular user logged in at the next page? And more importantly, output detailed information of the logged in user on that next page? More technically, to output properties of the username which are in different tables in the database.

Now I know I should begin with:

`<?php
     session_start();

     $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
?>`

But how do I specify assigning the value of "$user_name" to the value inputted in the username textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks, man. If I'm using Recordsets, what about trying to display the properties of this user from the database?

Comment: You can buddy. Run a select query and then use while loop to retieve data and use them to assign it to sessions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think using sessions is unnecessary for this task.

Simply search the database for the user's name once they log in and display this back to the page. Only store what's needed in sessions, databases are a more efficient storage medium.

Comment: There are many users in the database, I'll have to use the name specific user given which are many

Comment: Don't really understand the question, sorry I couldn't help